# node.js - Permission Denied when Reading and Writing to Firebase Database

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions, firebase-admin

I'm having issues reading and writing a value in Firebase Realtime Database in a Firebase function written in Node.js. I ran this when I was trying to solve another issue and thought I should go back to basics and make sure basic read/write is working.

When I trigger the function, this error shows up in the console:

Error: permission_denied at /: Client doesn't have permission to access the desired data.

All of the service accounts that have been set up with Editor permissions, so I'm not sure why the information can't be read from here. If anyone knows what might be going on, please let me know.

My code:

```
exports.identifyUpdate = functions.storage.object().onFinalize((object) => {

firebase.initializeApp({
    apiKey: "AAAAbp85RXQ:APA91bHp6H5aBwDYXZISSQJkpL8WFRnMgFPEJQyFcUxOPnRMdNnEfSfuGfYO-Oiv8-hn6gjq_YBDgi3UoGtxWFKSoFlN8tG8TsV8RxPvDLrnH8Yz6Q7Gby6-McXlJY3EcQlN4gQJrm4S",
    authDomain: "timeless-5aa87.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://timeless-5aa87.firebaseio.com",
    storageBucket: "timeless-5aa87.appspot.com",
   });
   var ref = firebase.app().database().ref();
   ref.once("value").then(function (snap) {
    console.log("snap.val()", snap.val());
    });
});
```

Comment: Are you using the admin SDK? Also I see nothing about a service account in the code you provided.

Comment: I'm using the regular Firebase for Web to access the database. I used the npm library to install it and require('firebase')

Comment: Is it possible to use that SDK in [Firebase Function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/) (Or am I confusing about what you are using?)

Comment: I think it is possible, that may solve my issues with authenticating. Thanks for the suggestion!